# Cannot find module 'firebase' or its corresponding type declarations. React + TypeScript + Firebase

Tags: typescript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, create-react-app

I wanted to change my React project that i worked on in january to use typescript. I installed all types and packages the only file that is giving me problems is the `firebase` file.

This is wat i was having back then Using `js`.

```js
import firebase from "firebase";
import "firebase/storage";
import "firebase/auth";
import "firebase/firestore";
import dotenv from "dotenv";

dotenv.config();

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: process.env.API_KEY,
  authDomain: process.env.AUTH_DOMAIN,
  projectId: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
  storageBucket: process.env.STORAGE_BUCKET,
  messagingSenderId: process.env.MESSAGING_SENDER_ID,
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  measurementId: process.env.MEASUREMENT_ID,
};
const app =
  firebase.apps.length > 0
    ? firebase.app()
    : firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

const auth = app.auth();
const db = app.firestore();
const storage = app.storage();
const timestamp = firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp();

const EmailProvider = new firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider();
const _ = {
  auth,
  db,
  storage,
  timestamp,
  EmailProvider,
};
export default _;
```

When i change to typescript I'm getting this error as i hover on the line `import firebase from "firebase";` in vscode.

```
Cannot find module 'firebase' or its corresponding type declarations.
```

This is my package.json and im using `yarn`:

```json
{
  ...
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    ..
    "firebase": "^9.0.0",
    ...
  },
  "scripts": {
 ..
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
   ..
  },
  "browserslist": {
 ..
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.8"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
"firebase": "^9.0.0",
// ...
"@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",
```

You may notice that these are very different version numbers. That's because firebase comes with types built in, and so the @types/firebase package is no longer needed and hasn't been updated in 4 years. Delete `"@types/firebase": "^3.2.1",` from your package.json and re-run yarn

Answer (score 24):

it's because the default import is from `firebase/app` and not `firebase`

Have a nice day :)

Edit: Didn't see that you were using the V9 of the SDK. With this version the initialization and all the logic with firebase is not the same.
Follow this guide to update your code https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/modular-upgrade

Comment: For any one still having an issue, they have updated it to

'firebase/compat/app'

Comment: Such a saviour! This was the issue! Thanks!